# Prolog predicate to unzip lists

Tags: list, prolog

I have written a prolog predicate **my_unzip/2** that should unzip lists of any size. I can't seem to get the correct output and I am new to prolog.

```
my_unzip([], [[],[]]). 
my_unzip([X], [[X], []]). 
my_unzip([F, S | T], [[F|TS], [S|TF]]) :- my_unzip(T, [TS, TF]).
```

example:

```
 my_unzip(X,[[a,b],[c,d]]).
```

should return

```
X = [[a,c],[b,d]]
```

but I am getting

```
X = [a, c, b, d]
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the third clause.Nevertheless, the result ```X = [a, b, c, d]``` for the query ```my_unzip (X, [[a, c], [b, d]])``` is correct . The order of the parameters is what causes confusion. For example, ```my_unzip([a, c, b, d], [Y,Z])``` must produce ```Y = [a, b]``` and  ```Z = [c, d] ```

Comment: @slago how would i fix this to output X = [[a,c],[b,d]]? What order should the parameters be in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_unzip([  F, S | T], [[F|TS], [S|TF]]) :- my_unzip(T, [TS, TF]).
```

gives you

```
X = [       a, c , .......
```

but you want

```
X = [      [a, c], .......
```

thus the needed change is, correspondingly,

```
my_unzip([ …F, S…| T], ......
```

(you'll need to make the corresponding change, replacing the `…`s with the actual syntactic elements).